# Pinterest image button getting in the way of my :hover css

Tags: css, hover, pinterest

I have some pseudo code like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hiddenatfirst">
      <img>
      <img>
      <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css like so:

```
.hiddenatfirst{
display:none;
}

.container:hover .hiddenatfirst{
display:block;
}

.hiddenatfirst:hover{
display:block;
}
```

The problem is - I have a design website and a lot of visitors have the pinterst extension installed. When someone hovers over the pin-it button that gets added to the images inside the .hiddenatfirst div the div gets hidden again.

I don't want to remove the pin-it buttons from the images but I don't want them to get in the way of the :hover events.

Any ideas?

Apologies for the pseudo-code, the real code is pretty messy and in staging! Hopefully this explains what I need.

Thanks

PS - if you look at the .third-level-menu in the navigation here you'll see it in action (note you'll need the pinterest chrome extension installed)

http://smith-hoyt.myshopify.com/?preview_theme_id=12397927

PPS - this is a crappy GIF but I think shows what's happening too:

http://recordit.co/anNtu8W1Vo

PPPS - you can see the pin-it button that pinterest adds to each image in this image: https://twitter.com/tomcritchlow/status/573920066124836864/photo/1

Comment: If you look at the navigation here you'll see it in action: http://smith-hoyt.myshopify.com/?preview_theme_id=12397927

Comment: Can you please find out, and expose, how is html structured when the pinterest icon is added?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the problem is that 'Pin it' button is absolutely positioned on top of the image, but it's not the container's child, so hover on it hides the image like on the following sample:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 315px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.hiddenatfirst {
  display: none;
}
#pinit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 32px;
}
.container:hover .hiddenatfirst {
  display: block;
}
.hiddenatfirst:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hiddenatfirst">
    <img src='https://dq1eylutsoz4u.cloudfront.net/2014/10/sf-cat.jpg' />
  </div>
</div>
<img id='pinit' src='http://www.brandaiddesignco.com/insights/PinIt.png' />
```

What you can do is using JavaScript or jQuery find all the 'Pin it' buttons and move them to the appropriate containers with the positions recalculation, so the result HTML will be like the following:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 315px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.hiddenatfirst {
  display: none;
}
#pinit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 32px;
}
.container:hover .hiddenatfirst {
  display: block;
}
.hiddenatfirst:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hiddenatfirst">
    <img src='https://dq1eylutsoz4u.cloudfront.net/2014/10/sf-cat.jpg' />
    <img id='pinit' src='http://www.brandaiddesignco.com/insights/PinIt.png' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the javascript solution above, since these images are small and in the navigation I found a way to remove the pin-it button, simply add to each image:

```
nopin="nopin"
```

As per the documentation here:

https://developers.pinterest.com/on_hover_pin_it_buttons/